# How to install mcrypt for PHP 7.4 on Aws Linux 2?

Tags: php, amazon-ec2, php-fpm, amazon-linux-2

I'm trying to install mcrypt with

`yum install php-mcrypt`

but run into this dependency error:

```
Error: Package: php-mcrypt-5.4.16-9.el7.x86_64 (epel)
Requires: php(api) = 20100412-64
installed: php-common-7.4.30-1.amzn2.x86_64 (@amzn2extra-php7.4)
php(api) = 20190902-64
```

So far I've tried

- yum update
- Re-installing epel
- Installing libmcrypt-devel

Obviously seems like I have an incorrect version of something but I'm not sure what is meant by `php(api) = 20100412-64`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to resolve this with the following commands:

```
dnf install -y epel-release
yum install --enablerepo=epel -y gcc libmcrypt-devel make
pecl install mcrypt-1.0.3
echo 'extension=mcrypt.so' > /etc/php.d/20-mcrypt.ini
systemctl restart php-fpm.service
systemctl restart httpd.service
```